# nodejs multipart/formData Request

Tags: node.js

I am noobie in multipart/formdata request in node js.

I am crawling a website which does multipart/formdata request.This is how it does :

```
url : https://example.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=----

formdata : 
------------------------------7a9cd2dc11c1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="to"

destination@email.com
------------------------------7a9cd2dc11c1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="from"

recipient@email.com
------------------------------7a9cd2dc11c1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

subject line
------------------------------7a9cd2dc11c1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

This content does not matter.
------------------------------7a9cd2dc11c1--
```

am using request module of node js for doing that. Help, i need example..

Comment: What do you need an example of? How to parse formdata on the server?

Comment: how to send post multipart/formData from nodejs request to some site